# Cauchy integral formula and contour

Tags: complex-analysis

I was doing fourier transform of lorentzian function

$$
B(k)=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{k-k0}{\Delta k}\right)^2}
=\frac{\Delta k^2}{\Delta k^2+\left(k-k_0\right)^2}
$$

$B(k)$ is neither even nor odd function, so Fourier transform of $B(k)$

$$
\mathscr{F}[B(k)]=\Delta k^2\int_{\infty}^{\infty}
\frac{e^{-ik\delta}}{\Delta k^2+\left(k-k_0\right)^2}dk
$$

substitution
$
k-k_0=\kappa
$
, $\qquad
k=k_0+\kappa
$

$$
\mathscr{F}[B(k)]=\Delta k^2e^{-ik_0\delta}\int_{\infty}^{\infty}
\frac{e^{-i\kappa\delta}}{\Delta k^2+\kappa^2}d\kappa
=
\Delta k^2e^{-ik_0\delta}\int_{\infty}^{\infty}
\frac{e^{-i\kappa\delta}}{(\kappa+i\Delta k)(\kappa-i\Delta k)}
d\kappa
$$

Cauchy's integral formula, I used the formula once for each pole.

When $\delta<0$, the contour is on the upper plane, and it is counter clockwise

$$
\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(\kappa)e^{-i\kappa\delta}d\kappa=2\pi i \sum Res[f(\kappa)e^{-i\kappa\delta}]
$$

$$
\mathscr{F}[B(k)]
=
2\pi i \Delta k^2e^{-ik_0\delta} \frac{e^{-\Delta k\delta}}{2i\Delta k}
=
\pi \Delta k e^{-ik_0\delta}e^{-\Delta k\delta}
$$

When $\delta>0$, the contour is on the lower plane, and it is clockwise (which adds minus(-) sign to the integral)

$$
\mathscr{F}[B(k)]
=
-2\pi i \Delta k^2e^{-ik_0\delta} \frac{e^{\Delta k\delta}}{-2i\Delta k}
=
\pi \Delta k e^{-ik_0\delta}e^{\Delta k\delta}
$$

Together they comprise

$$
\pi \Delta k e^{-\Delta k |\delta|-ik_0\delta}
$$

This is some other's work, and there is something I quite don't understand.

How does $\delta>0$ corresponds to upper plane and $\delta<0$ to lower plane?

(besides, did I wrote the correct answer for FT?)

Comment: You have a sign error in the exponent, it's $e^{-\Delta k \lvert\delta\rvert - i k_0\delta}$.

Comment: Thank you for your keen observation

Comment: uh.. I checked again, i think it is still $e^{\Delta k}$

Comment: No, for $\delta < 0$, when we use the semicircle in the upper half-plane, we must plug $i\Delta k$ into $e^{-i\kappa\delta}$, and $-i\cdot (i\Delta k) = \Delta k$, so we get $e^{\Delta k\delta} = e^{-\Delta k\lvert\delta\rvert}$ then.

Comment: oh. you're right. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $\delta<0$ the integration over a semi-circular contour $C_R$, with radius $R$ and centered at the origin in the upper-half plane becomes

$$\int_{C_R}\frac{e^{-i\delta z}}{z^2-\Delta k^2}\,dz = \int_0^\pi \frac{e^{-i\delta R e^{i\phi}}}{R^2e^{i2\phi}-\Delta k^2}(iRe^{i\phi})\,d\phi$$

Note that the term $e^{-i\delta R e^{i\phi}}=e^{-i\delta R\cos(\phi)}e^{\delta R\sin(\phi)}$ decays exponentially for $0<\phi <\pi$ as $R\to \infty$ when $\delta<0$.  Therefore, as $R\to \infty$ the integral over $C_R$ vanishes.

> It is important to point out that this last statement is not obvious since for $\phi \approx 0$ and $\phi \approx \pi$ the exponential is close to zero for fixed $R$.  To show that the integral vanishes, we write the following estimates for $R>\Delta k$:
>
> $$\begin{align}\left|\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{-i\delta R e^{i\phi}}}{R^2e^{i2\phi}-\Delta k^2}(iRe^{i\phi})\,d\phi\right|&\le \int_0^\pi \frac{Re^{\delta R\sin(\phi)}}{|R^2e^{i2\phi}-\Delta k^2|}\,d\phi\\\\&\le \frac{2R}{R^2-\Delta k^2}\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{2 \delta R\,\phi/\pi }\,d\phi\\\\&=\frac{\pi(1-e^{-|\delta| R})}{|\delta| (R^2-\Delta k^2)}\end{align}$$  So, it is evident that as $R\to \infty$, the integral over $C_R$ tends to $0$.  Note that in the development, we used $\sin(\phi)\ge 2\phi/\pi$ for $0\le \phi\le \pi/2$.

However, when $\delta>0$, the term $e^{-i\delta R e^{i\phi}}=e^{-i\delta R\cos(\phi)}e^{\delta R\sin(\phi)}$ increases exponentially for $0<\phi <\pi$ as $R\to \infty$.  Therefore, when $\delta >0$, we close the contour with the semi-circular arc $C'_{R}$, with radius $R$ and centered at the origin in the lower-half plane.  On $C'_{R}$, the exponential term decays as $R\to \infty$ and the integration over $C'_{R}$ approaches zero.

Answer (score 2):

Cauchy's formula requires a closed contour in the complex plane.  We typically close the contour with a semicircle in the upper or lower half plane.  When $\delta \lt 0$, the integral over the semicircle in the upper half plane vanishes (and that over the lower half plane diverges), so we use the upper half plane.  Vice-versa for $\delta \lt 0$.